# Solving wave equation with Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, wave-equation

I want to solve the following wave equation:
$$
\frac {\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u=c^{2}\frac {\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u,\quad -\infty<x<\infty,\text{ }0<t<\infty
$$
subject to the initial condition $u(x,0)=0$ and $\partial u/\partial t=\delta(x)$ at $t=0$, and the boundary conditions $u(x,t)\to 0$ as $x\to \pm \infty$.

What I've done is:

Denote the Fourier transform with respect to $x$ by $\mathcal {F}_{x}$. The we get
$$
\frac {\partial^2}{\partial t^2}U(k,t)+c^{2}k^{2}U(k,t)=0,
$$
where $U(k,t)=\mathcal {F}_{x}\left[u(x,t)\right]$. The solution to the ODE for $U$ is given by
$$
U(k,t)=A(k)\cos (ckt)+B(k)\sin (ckt).
$$
The initial condition suggests that $A(k)=U(k,0)=0$ and $ckB(k)=U_{t}(k,0)=\mathcal {F}_{x}\left[\delta(x)\right]=1$. Therefore, we get
$$
U(k,t)=\frac {1}{ck}\sin (ckt).
$$
The inverse Fourier transform of $U(k,t)$ gives
$$
u(x,t)=\frac {1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {1}{ck}\sin (ckt)e^{-ikx}\, dk=\frac {1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {1}{i2ck}e^{-ik(x-ct)}\, dk-\frac {1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {1}{i2ck}e^{-ik(x+ct)}dk
$$
I wonder how to go from here. It seems like these two integrals depend on the sign of $x-ct$ and $x+ct$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrals do depend on the signs of $x\pm ct$.  We exploit the symmetry to write

$$\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=\frac1{4\pi c}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(k(x+ct))}{k}\,dk-\frac1{4\pi c}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(k(x-ct))}{k}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac1{4 c}\left( \text{sgn}(x+ct)-\text{sgn}(x-ct)\right)\\\\
&=\begin{cases}\frac1{2c}&,|x|\le ct\\\\0&,\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Should it be $1/2c$ for $|x|\leq ct$?

Comment: Okay, I feel like when $-ct<x<ct$, $x-ct<0$, which means that sgn$(x-ct)=-1$ instead of $0$.

Comment: Indeed.  Good catch.  I've edited accordingly.